# ctrl+alt+numpad 0 is not working on a project

Tags: camera

I am following a tutorial online and the camera is not capturing the active view port when I press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

I tried it with a different cube in a new file and it was working absolutely fine but when I tried it on the stuff I was making, it was just capturing just a small portion, it looks something like this: (refer pic 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Have you checked to see if your NumLock key is on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you forget to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or it is somehow not working? In the first picture the cube is selected, and the second picture is from inside the cube. You usually get this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> > *Set Active Object As Camera*.

Or check in the 3D Viewport menu, look at *View* > *Align View* > *Align Active Camera to View* and also *View* > *Cameras* > *Set Active Object As Camera* which shortcuts are given there, maybe you changed something accidentally.

Another possibility: you accidentally set the cube as camera. If you then go into any different view and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, the cube gets aligned to the view but you are also seeing the inside of the cube again, because it is the active camera.

**EDIT:** Now that I see the XYZ orientation axis in your second screenshot, my last suggestion seems most likely.

Comment: Thank you so much man ! The problem was actually the same which you just mentioned, I pressed Ctrl + Numpad 0 by mistake ! I fixed it now, thank you so much for your help !!